# Can I create a script, "Virtual Environment" and run it in crontab?

Tags: python, django, linux, bash, unix

They help me, they know I need to run a script to start the services, I use Django with Python and ubuntu server.

I have been seeing many examples in crontab, which I will use, every time I restart the server, I run the Script, which contains the command to run the virtual environment and in addition to the command "python3 manage.py runserver_plus", apart was to see restart the server all nights, I was also successful with crontab, but I can't execute what the script contains. They can help me, I am not very expert, but I managed to do something.
Is it the path of the script?

[image]

Tried running the command directly, got no results.

[image]

```
I write the following.

root@server:/home/admin-server# pwd
/home/admin-server 

root@server:/home/admin-server# ls -l
drwxrwxr 3 admin-server   admin-server 4096 Nov 20 17:25 control_flota
-rwxr--r-- 1 root    root.  141 Nov 20 18:00  server_script.sh
```

Script new
I still have no results: /, I don't know why?

```
#!bin/bash
echo "Welcome"
cd /home/admin-server/control_flota/
source venvp1/bin/activate
echo "Thanks"
```

Comment: The new script stops at activating the virtual environment; where’s the last command? `python3 manage.py runserver_plus`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can activate the **Virtual Environment** from within the shell script, prior to running any **manage.py** commands

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /your_code_directory
source env/bin/activate
python ./manage.py runserver_plus
```

Ensure you save the file with the **.sh** extension, then give it execute rights:

```
chmod u+x your_script.sh
```

You should then be able to call from cron; sudo cron if you run into permissions issues

Comment: Interesting, I'll try to show the result, thanks... :)

Comment: @JorgeToro - You're welcome mate! If this helps, kindly mark as the accepted answer

Comment: I write the following.

root @ server: / home / admin-server # pwd
/home/admin-server

root @ server: / home / admin-server # ls -l

drwxrwxr 3 admin-server admin-server 4096 Nov 20 17:25 control_fleet
-rwxr - r-- 1 root root. 141 Nov 20 18:00 server_script.sh
          Script 
#!/bin/bash
echo "Welcome"
cd /home/admin-server/control_flota/
source venvp1/bin/activate
echo "Thanks"

Comment: @JorgeToro - Is your question answered? If so, kindly mark my answer as accepted to close the loop

Comment: hace, I still don't have the solution, I run the command lines, I give it permissions, it doesn't give me an error, but I can't activate the active font in a Script, I don't know what could it be?

Comment: Thans, very very Good... :)